# BJP4 Exercise 3.20: inputBirthday

Tags: java, methods, edx

Write a method called inputBirthday that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and prompts the user to enter a month, day, and year of birth, then prints the birthdate in a suitable format. Here is an example dialogue with the user:

I need to take this input like this-

> > On what day of the month were you born? 8
> >     What is the name of the month in which you were born? May
> >     During what year were you born? 1981

output should be like this-

**You were born on May 8, 1981. You're mighty old!**

[image: i'm getting this kind of error]

[image: but this code works fine in intellij]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    inputBirthday();
}


  public static void inputBirthday() {
      Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("On what day of the month were you born? ");
      int inputDay = abc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("What is the name of the month in which you were born? ");
      String inputMonth = abc.next();
      System.out.println("During what year were you born? ");
      int inputYear = abc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You were born on " + inputMonth + " " + inputDay + "," + " " + inputYear + "." + " You're mighty old!");
}
```

Comment: Can not see the end of the text of the method - are you closing the string/method correctly?

Comment: Yeah last line is like this - **System.out.println("You were born on " + a + " " + b + "," + " " + c + "." + " You're mighty old!");**

Comment: Instead of showing image try to copy paste the code.

Comment: Maybe problem with the website, as you say works OK with intellij

Comment: I typed the whole code in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // either instantiate the enclosing class, or make inputBirthday static
    inputBirthday(in);
    }

  public static void inputBirthday(Scanner abc)
 {
    System.out.print("On what day of the month were you born? ");
    int inputDay = abc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the name of the month in which you were born? ");
    String inputMonth = abc.next();
    System.out.print("During what year were you born? ");
    int inputYear = abc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You were born on " + inputMonth + " " + inputDay + "," + " " + inputYear + "." + " You're mighty old!");
    }
```

finally it worked and code passed all tests

[test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohYe.png)

Comment: Thanks to all of you who had helped me solving this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the requirements specifically state you are to write a *method* called `inputBirthday` that accepts a `Scanner` object. You have written a `main` method and then a method `inputBirthday` that is accepting `String, int, int`.

Move the code from the `main` method to the `inputBirthday` method, get rid of the scanner instantiation, and modify the `inputBirthday` method to accept a scanner (probably `inputBirthday(Scanner abc)`.

The code, as written, works in intellij because it is a complete program. But for the site, they expect a specific method signature. This approach is no different than what `leetcode` or other such on-line code places expect.

The OP made an edit, but again, the requirements stipulate that the approach should be something like:

```
public void inputBirthday(Scanner abc) {
    System.out.println("On what day of the month were you born? ");
    int inputDay = abc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the name of the month in which you were born? ");
    String inputMonth = abc.next();
    System.out.println("During what year were you born? ");
    int inputYear = abc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You were born on " + inputMonth + " " + inputDay + "," + " " + inputYear + "." + " You're mighty old!");
}
```

So, again:

- get the method signature to match the requirement (it isn't clear if it is supposed to be static, so it might need to be `public static inputBirthday(Scanner abc)`).
- Do not instantiate a scanner in the `inputBirthday` method.

To test from an IDE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  // either instantiate the enclosing class, or make inputBirthday static
  inputBirthday(in);
}
```

Comment: I have already done what you're telling me to do but still its showing the same error

Comment: @PratikSingh, if so, then please edit your question to show the actual current state of your code.

Comment: you can see modified code above please add **import java.util.Scanner;**  in line 1

Comment: @PratikSingh, please see the edits I just made. The requirements specifically state a method `inputBirthday` accepting a parameter of a `Scanner`. You changed so the `inputBirthday` didn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void inputBirthday(Scanner input) {
     Scanner start = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("On what day of the month were you born? ");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the name of the month in which you were born? ");
    String month = input.next();
    System.out.print("During what year were you born? ");
    int year = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("You were born on " + month + " " + day + "," + " " + year + "." + " You're mighty old!");
}
```

Comment: This is the most simplest code you can type to get it correct!

Comment: Why are you initializing a new Scanner, that you're not using? And why are you using a parameter for the Scanner? Also.. this is basically identical to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115552/12695027) given by Pratik Singh and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114886/12695027) by KevinO. Can you explain how this answer adds value?